# How to shortened query database to dropdown option without relation widget October CMS

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I've already done this in my October CMS project

```
public function getJenisKebOptions(){

    $kebum = Db::table('mismaiti_settingwarta_jeniskeb')->select('jeniskeb')->where('katkeb','Umum/Raya')->get(); 

    $kebums = json_decode(json_encode($kebum),true) ;

    $ibum = array_values($kebums[0]);  
    $ibum1 = array_values($kebums[1]);
    $ibum2 = array_values($kebums[2]);    


    return ['jeniskeb' => $ibum,$ibum1,$ibum2 ];

}
```

I need to shortened this, so when there is more three arrays, I don't have to write long line of code.

`edited(solved)`

```
public function getJenisKebOptions(){

    $kebum = Db::table('mismaiti_settingwarta_jeniskeb')->where('katkeb','Umum/Raya')->pluck('jeniskeb','jeniskeb');         

    return $kebum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused with your code

> return ['jeniskeb' => $ibum,$ibum1,$ibum2 ];

what output exactly you need to return. `getJenisKebOptions` with that you need to return options for `jenis_keb` and it must be in `key => value` format so i suggest to user last trick to return `options` in just 2 line of code.

for general use you can use below code:

You can replace your code

```
$kebums = json_decode(json_encode($kebum),true) ;

$ibum = array_values($kebums[0]);  
$ibum1 = array_values($kebums[1]);
$ibum2 = array_values($kebums[2]);

return ['jeniskeb' => $ibum,$ibum1,$ibum2 ];
```

> With

```
$kebums = json_decode(json_encode($kebum),true);

$returnArray = [];
foreach ($kebums as $values) {
    $returnArray[] = $values;
}

return ['jeniskeb' => $returnArray];
```

> if you want more professional way you can use built in function `pluck`

```
public function getJenisKebOptions(){

    // MismaitiSettingwartaJeniskeb <= your model
    $items = MismaitiSettingwartaJeniskeb::where('katkeb', 'Umum/Raya')
                                      ->pluck('jeniskeb', 'id');
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: $kebums = json_decode(json_encode($kebum),true);

$returnArray = [];
foreach ($kebums as $values) {
    $returnArray[] = $values;
}

return ['jeniskeb' => $returnArray];

Comment: `strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: Model Jeniskeb it's on different plugin.. so it also return an error for using `pluck`  function

Comment: i have the solution `$kebum = Db::table('mismaiti_settingwarta_jeniskeb')->where('katkeb','Umum/Raya')->pluck('jeniskeb','jeniskeb');         

        return $kebum;`